# How does the naturalness problem of the Higgs mass changes depending on the cut off scale of the Standard Model (SM)?

Tags: standard-model, renormalization, higgs, effective-field-theory, fine-tuning

In [this year's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06131.pdf) (check introduction) James D. Wells brings Susskind's 1979 argument that the SM is valid to a very high energy scale, say the Planck scale, $\Lambda \approx M_{Pl} \approx 10^{18} GeV$. This implies that the bare mass of the Higgs is very large, and thus for the effective (experimental) Higgs mass to be 125GeV there must be a very large fine tuning so the quantum corrections can cancel that big number. The equation helps understand the problem:
$$ m_H^2=m_{bare}^2 +\frac{y_t^2}{16\pi^2}\Lambda^2 +\delta\cal O (m_{weak}^2),$$
where $m_H$ is the Higgs effective mass, $m_{bare}$ its bare mass and the other two terms the quantum corrections. Note this equation highlights the contribution of the top quark loop only.

**My questions are:**

1. How would the Higgs bare mass change if $\Lambda \ll M_{Pl}$? I imagine it would be much smaller, so the fine tuning wouldn't be a problem. Am I right?
2. How can one calculate that? An equation (or even a proportionality relation) relating $m_{bare}$ to $\Lambda$ would be enough. Resources are welcome.

Comment: Did you just use scientific notation together with an SI scale prefix?

Comment: Your equation *is* an equation relating $m_\mathrm{bare}$ to $\Lambda$. What else do you need?

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean, $10^{18} GeV = 1^{27} eV$

Comment: @JanDvorak In particle physics is not unnatural to mix scientific notation and an SI prefix. We are familiar with $\mathrm{GeV}$ and so expressing numbers in that units feels natural to us, even if we need to include a high power of 10.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform How could I not have seen it? Tks.